# Is the Petersen Graph k-partite?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I am trying to find the smallest k for which the Petersen graph on 10 vertices is k-partite. I know that is not bipartite by brute force, however I'm not sure how best to tackle for larger k? Is there a better method than trial and error of different vertex classes (both in terms of which vertices they contain and the number of vertices in each)?

Comment: The chromatic number of the Petersen graph is $3$.

Comment: @michaelbiro can you provide me with a proof?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Petersen graph is not bipartite, because it has a 5-cycle. It is 3-colorable. You can find such a coloring [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petersen_graph), midway down the page on the right. So the smallest $k$ for which the Petersen graph is $k$-partite is $k=3$.

Comment: I'm not familiar with graph colouring, could I form an isomorphism with K$3,3,3$?

Comment: @user43290 The colors in a vertex coloring can represent partite classes. So in the coloring given midway down that page, the 4 red vertices are in one class, the 3 blue vertices in a second class, and the 3 green vertices in the third class. The Petersen graph is not isomorphic to $K_{3,3,3}$ because $K_{3,3,3}$ has 9 vertices, while the Petersen graph has 10.

Comment: @user43290 Look at this picture http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petersen_graph#/media/File:Petersen_graph_3-coloring.svg The 4 red, 3 green and 3 blue vertices are exactly the splitting of $K_{4,3,3}$ and the Petersen graph is a sub-graph of $K_{4,3,3}$.